# python thread to sequentially process data

Tags: python, multithreading

I want two thread, that's say `thread1` and `thread2`. `thread1` takes 'c++' as input, and output ['c', '+', '+'], put it in a list, that's say `res`;
and `thread2` takes 'python' as input, and output ['p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n'], put it in `res`. So after processing, res will be  [['c', '+', '+'], ['p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n']], not [['p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n'], ['c', '+', '+']]. The logic is like the following code, but I want a thread version code.

```
train_set = [
    'c++',
    'python',
]

def to_list(item):
    return list(item)

res = list(map(to_list, train_set))
print(res) # [['c', '+', '+'], ['p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably best off using [`queue` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html), which is designed for passing messages between threads. In particular, if you call the `get()` method on the queue, but the queue is currently empty, it will wait until a message becomes available. You will need a queue for each of your two worker threads, and also a third for the original thread to get results. I'm afraid I'm not going to write your code for you! But the example on the page I linked to illustrates how to use that class.

Answer (score 0):

```
import thread

def func(Inp, res):
    res.append(list(Inp))
    return res

train_set = ['c++', 'python']
result=[]

try:
   thread.start_new_thread(func,(train_set[0],result))
   thread.start_new_thread(func,(train_set[1],result))
except:
   print "Error: unable to start thread"

for i in range(20):
   print(result)
   pass
```

but this task could be done easily this way:

```
>>> train_set = [
...     'c++',
...     'python',
... ]
>>> res=[list(i) for i in train_set]
>>> res
[['c', '+', '+'], ['p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n']]
```

Comment: not problem of python version, time for execution of threads, I have edited my post, it will run 20 time and give time sufficient to execute both threads.

Comment: @Dadep Certainly the `print` statement will not work on Python 3, so you have not tested on that version.